# export 'RestService' (imported as 'RestService') was not found in './rest.service.interface' (module has no exports) after update vom Angular 7 to 12

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi guys I've a problem I cannot fix for several hours now.
I have an interface:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { L10nTranslationService } from 'angular-l10n';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { APIConfigService } from '../../api.config.service';

import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service';
import { LoggerService } from '../../shared/logger.service';
import { Kernantwort } from '../../shared/response/kernantwort.model';
import { OaseListe } from './oaseliste.model';

export declare class RestService {
  isRequestRunning: boolean;
  fehler: Kernantwort;
  apiUrlPrefix: string;
  apiUrlListId: string;
  API_LIST: string;
  API_CREATE: string;
  API_UPDATE: string;
  API_DELETE: string;
  constructor(authService: AuthService, http: HttpClient, translation: L10nTranslationService, apiConfigService: APIConfigService, _logger: LoggerService);
  init(): any;
  liste(page: number, size: number, sort: string, sortdirection: string, search: string): Observable<OaseListe<any>>;
  speichernAendern(element: any): Observable<any>;
  loeschen(id: number): Observable<any>;
  handleError(error: Response | any, prefix: string): Kernantwort;
  getApiBaseUrl(): string;
  getApiUrl(): string;
}
```

And the implementation of this interface:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, ResponseType } from '@angular/http';
import { L10nTranslationService } from 'angular-l10n';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, Observable, share, throwError as observableThrowError } from 'rxjs';

import { APIConfigService } from '../../api.config.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service';
import { LoggerService } from '../../shared/logger.service';
import { Httpstatus } from '../../shared/response/httpstatus.model';
import { Kernantwort } from '../../shared/response/kernantwort.model';
import { OaseListe } from './oaseliste.model';
import { RestService } from './rest.service.interface';

const PATH_FILE = 'app/protected/immerdrin/rest.service.impl.ts';

@Injectable()
export class RestServiceImpl extends RestService {
  isRequestRunning = false;
  fehler: Kernantwort = null;
  apiUrlPrefix: string = null;
  apiUrlListId: string = null;

  API_LIST = 'liste';
  API_CREATE = 'hinzufuegen';
  API_UPDATE = 'bearbeiten';
  API_DELETE = 'loeschen';

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public http: HttpClient,
    public translation: L10nTranslationService,
    public apiConfigService: APIConfigService,
    public _logger: LoggerService
  ) {
    super(authService, http, translation,apiConfigService, _logger);
    this.init();
  }
```

When I try to start the application I get the following error:

> ./src/app/protected/immerdrin/rest.service.impl.ts:19:32-43 - Error:
> export 'RestService' (imported as 'RestService') was not found in
> './rest.service.interface' (module has no exports)

And I have no clue why I get this error message? Because in Angular 7 the exact same code worked well, but now after update to Angular 12 this error occurs.
Is anybody able to help me?

Thanks in advance
OASE

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you have

```
export class RestServiceImpl extends RestService
```

instead:

```
export class RestServiceImpl implement RestService
```

Or maybe when you declare this:

```
export declare class RestService {
```

declare an interface instead:

```
export declare interface RestService {
```

Even, afterwards, you could try both solutions at the same time.

Comment: Hi Juan,
thank you for your help. I tried to change the code as you described above. This worked fine for the above example. BUT then I got errors in all other components where I used the RestService. Because there is the `providers: [{provide: RestService, useExisting: RestServiceImpl}]` command. And at this line the error stated: RestService is imported as type but used as value.
So I changed the definition of the RestService to: `export abstract class RestService`
Then I only had to remove the constructor method and the projects compiles right now.
So THANK you very much for your hint!!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I had to change de definition of the RestService like this. With this definition the code compiles fine in Angular 12:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Kernantwort } from '../../shared/response/kernantwort.model';
import { OaseListe } from './oaseliste.model';

//
export abstract class RestService {
  isRequestRunning: boolean;
  fehler: Kernantwort;
  apiUrlPrefix: string;
  apiUrlListId: string;
  API_LIST: string;
  API_CREATE: string;
  API_UPDATE: string;
  API_DELETE: string;
  abstract init(): any;
  abstract liste(page: number, size: number, sort: string, sortdirection: string, search: string): Observable<OaseListe<any>>;
  abstract speichernAendern(element: any): Observable<any>;
  abstract loeschen(id: number): Observable<any>;
  abstract handleError(error: Response | any, prefix: string): Kernantwort;
  abstract getApiBaseUrl(): string;
  abstract getApiUrl(): string;
}
```

As you can see I changed the Class to an abstract class and therefore I had to remove the constructor Method which is not available in an abstract class.